# For odd $n$, there is an $m$ such that $n \mid 2^m-1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

I am really stuck with this question:

> Suppose $n$ is an odd positive integer. Prove that there exists a positive integer $m$ such that (2^m − 1)\n .
>   (Here, “divides” means that when 2^m − 1 is divided by n.)

Comment: Probably m > 1.

Comment: For $k=1,2,\dots,n+1$, imagine computing the remainder when $2^k$ is divided by $n$. These remainders are not all distinct (Pigeonhole Principle). So there exist $1\le s\lt t\le n+1$ such that $2^s$ and $2^t$ have the same remainder. It follows that $n$ divides $2^t-2^s$, so $n$ divides $2^{t-s}-1$.

Comment: . So there exist 1≤s<t≤n+1 such that 2s and 2t have the same remainder. It follows that n divides 2t−2s, so n divides 2t−s−1. How did you arrive at conclusion 1≤s<t≤n+1.

Comment: There are only $n-1$ possible remainders, namely $0$ to $n-1$. So if we look at the remainders of $2^1,2^2,2^3,\dots,2^{n+1}$ two of these remainders (at least) must be the same.

Answer (score 5):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$It's standard thing.

$\gcd(2, n) = 1$, so $2$ is invertible in $\Z/n\Z$. The group $G$ of the invertible elements of $\Z/n\Z$ is finite, of order $m = \varphi(n)$. Thus $2^{m} \equiv 1 \pmod{n}$.